# JSOUP don't be able to extract dynamically generated DOM content in Android Studio

Tags: java, android

I use JSOUP to extract movie information on the web (as pictured) with JAVA on Android Studio. But I can not get the movie link (as shown). Please help me find a way to get the link highlighted in the picture.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QQ9T8.png)

Document document = Jsoup.connect(strings[0]).get();
Elements el = document.select("video.jw-video.jw-reset"); //-->Error

Comment: what is the error message you get?

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation, `Document#select(String tag)` accept the cssQuery only.

You may use `Document#getElementsByClass(String className)` in your case

[API documents](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Element.html#getElementsByClass-java.lang.String-)

[Official site](https://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/dom-navigation)

Comment: I tried debugging to watch the variable "document", but couldn't find the tag <video>

Comment: You may use `Document#outerHtml()`  to see the html from the website. Maybe the video DOM is not present.